# using np.select to create new column with multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to determine if my data crossed a line and from which direction. I got it working on a single index frame using np.select, however, I get all NaN when I try to do the same on a multiindex dataframe.

this is my helper function:

```
def calc_crossings_helper(df, line):
# define crossing conditions - corresponding choices are [1,-1] to denote direction, otherwise NaN
line_crossed_cond = [(df['Close'] < df[line]) & (df['Close'].shift(1) > df[line].shift(1)),
                     (df['Close'] > df[line]) & (df['Close'].shift(1) < df[line].shift(1))] 
return np.select(line_crossed_cond, [1, -1], default = np.nan)
```

Calling it like this:

```
df['Hcross'] = df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(calc_crossings_helper, ('highBound'))
```

the helper function returns:

```
Symbol
AAPL    [nan, nan, -1.0, nan, nan, 1.0, nan, -1.0, nan...
AMZN    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, -1.0, nan,...
```

but df['Hcross'] column is assigned all NaNs

```
                    Close   Hcross
Symbol Date                    
AAPL   2019-12-02   264.16  NaN
       2019-12-03   259.45  NaN
       2019-12-04   261.74  NaN
       2019-12-05   265.58  NaN
       2019-12-06   270.71  NaN
       2019-12-09   266.92  NaN
       2019-12-10   268.48  NaN
       2019-12-11   270.77  NaN
       2019-12-12   271.46  NaN
       2019-12-13   275.15  NaN
AMZN   2019-12-02  1781.60  NaN
       2019-12-03  1769.96  NaN
       2019-12-04  1760.69  NaN
       2019-12-05  1740.48  NaN
       2019-12-06  1751.60  NaN
       2019-12-09  1749.51  NaN
       2019-12-10  1739.21  NaN
       2019-12-11  1748.72  NaN
       2019-12-12  1760.33  NaN
       2019-12-13  1760.94  NaN
```

I think I need to somehow flatten the array returned from the helper function, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix is to return a Series indexed like the DataFrame. This gives the proper alignment since `np.select` returns an array of the same length of the DataFrame.

```
def calc_crossings_helper(df, line):
    # define crossing conditions - corresponding choices are [1,-1] to denote direction, otherwise NaN
    line_crossed_cond = [(df['Close'] < df[line]) & (df['Close'].shift(1) > df[line].shift(1)),
                         (df['Close'] > df[line]) & (df['Close'].shift(1) < df[line].shift(1))] 

    return pd.Series(np.select(line_crossed_cond, [1, -1], default = np.nan), index=df.index)
```

And now the `gropuby` return is a like-indexed MultiIndex:

```
df.assign(highbound=265).groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(calc_crossings_helper, ('highbound'))

Symbol  Date      
AAPL    2019-12-02    NaN
        2019-12-03    NaN
        2019-12-04    NaN
        2019-12-05   -1.0
        2019-12-06    NaN
        2019-12-09    NaN
        2019-12-10    NaN
        2019-12-11    NaN
        2019-12-12    NaN
        2019-12-13    NaN
AMZN    2019-12-02    NaN
        2019-12-03    NaN
        2019-12-04    NaN
        2019-12-05    NaN
        2019-12-06    NaN
        2019-12-09    NaN
        2019-12-10    NaN
        2019-12-11    NaN
        2019-12-12    NaN
        2019-12-13    NaN
```

---

Better yet, given your DataFrame sorting there's no need for a `groupby.apply()`. You can use `shift` on the Symbol level to add a grouping condition so you just need one `np.select` call.

```
line = 'highbound'
# Series b/c there is no pd.Index.shift method
s = pd.Series(df.index.get_level_values('Symbol'), index=df.index)

line_crossed_cond = [(s.eq(s.shift()) 
                      & (df['Close'] < df[line]) 
                      & (df['Close'].shift(1) > df[line].shift(1))),
                     (s.eq(s.shift())
                      & (df['Close'] > df[line]) 
                      & (df['Close'].shift(1) < df[line].shift(1)))]

df['Hcross'] = np.select(line_crossed_cond, [1, -1], default = np.nan)
```